# Why two/four threads is even slower than single thread doing vector inner_product in C++11 multithread coing?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Refering to a c++11 multi-threading [example](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/02/27/cpp-11-thread-tutorial-part-2/), I try to ues multi-threading to compute the vector dot_product result. The basic idea here is that we break the vector into two or four parts, and concurrent compute the partial_sum of each part. And do the summation after synchronize the two threads taks. Here, I only use CPU and RAM resources. Besides, I try create a big vector in order to cover the thread schedule ovehead.

*The problem is here that two/four threads is even slower than single thread. But the CPU utilization is much higher when using two threads. Hence, I believe two physical cores are used by the program.*

**The platform and running time results are given below. Some people said that running time is a little bit higher. I am not sure if the efficiency is related to OS. I haven't tested the code in Linux, anyone help me do the test?**

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

**Here is my thread implementation:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<vector>
#include<mutex>
#include<ctime>
#include<numeric>
#include<iterator>

using namespace std;
vector<int> boundary(int num, int parts)
{
    vector<int >bounds;
    int delta = num / parts;
    int remainder = num % parts;
    int prev = 0, next = 0;
    bounds.push_back(prev);

    for(int i = 0; i < parts; i++)
    {
        next = prev + delta;
        if(i == parts - 1)
            next = next + remainder;
        bounds.push_back(next);
        prev = next;
    } 

    return bounds;
}

void dot_product(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2, int& result, int L, int R, int tid)
{
    int partial_sum = 0;

    for(int i = L; i < R; i++)
        partial_sum += v1[i] * v2[i];

    //lock_guard<mutex> lock(barrier);
    //cout << "tid: " << tid<< endl;
    result = partial_sum;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    clock_t start, end;
    int numOfElement = 500000000;
    // Change the thread number here
    int numOfThread = 2;
    int result[numOfThread] = {0};
    vector<thread> threads;

    // Fill two vectors with some values 
    vector<int> v1(numOfElement, 1), v2(numOfElement, 2);

    // Split numOfElement into nr_threads parts
    vector<int> limits = boundary(numOfElement, numOfThread);

    start = clock();
    // Launch multi_threads:
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfThread; i++)
        threads.push_back(thread(dot_product, ref(v1), ref(v2), ref(result[i]), limits[i], limits[i+1], i)); 

    // Join the threads with the main thread    
    for(auto &t:threads)
        t.join();

    int sum = accumulate(result, result+numOfThread, 0);
    end = clock();  
    //cout << limits[0] <<" " << limits[1]<<" "<<limits[2]<<endl;
    cout << "results: " << sum << " time elapsed: "<< double(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Platform:**

OS: Win8 64bit

CPU: I3-3220 (2C4T)

RAM: 12G

IDE: Dev-C++ 5.11, TDM-GCC 4.9.2 release

**Results so far:**

1 Thread: 14.42 seconds, CPU: 60%, RAM: 3.82G(program only, revised it)

2 Threads: 19.65 seconds, CPU: 82%, RAM: 3.82G(program only, revised it)

4 Threads: 22.33 seconds, CPU: 99%, RAM: 3.82G(program only, revised it)

**Update:**
Referring to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348228/code-runs-6-times-slower-with-2-threads-than-with-1), I set the -O2 optimation for GCC at the expense of compilation time reported by this [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). Now the result seems normal as expectation, which is comparable to what @yzt reported below. Further, I replace the *clock* with *chrono* for high_resolution timming.

**New results:**

1 Thread: 0.57 seconds

2 Threads: 0.31 seconds

4 Threads: 0.28 seconds

**Seem that 2 thread almost approach the optimal speed in my CPU, I guess the reason behind this is that I3 only get 2 physical cores and 4 logical cores.**

Comment: Consider using a Task-Parallel library instead of using raw threads directly, because these libraries intelligently scale work according to the capabilities of the machine. If you're using Visual C++ on Windows consider using PPL ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx ), then please report back your findings.

Comment: Debug or release? On Windows there's a major difference in vector implementation, and the debug one may be locking mutexes / checking guards to see that there's no concurrent problematic access slowing down your test. Based on raw performance numbers I'd expect your full test to finish in about 1-2 seconds, so the 15 for one core is already very high.

Comment: There could also be some cache coherence issues. The threads are operating on some of the same data blocks. That may mean they are not able to use caching as aggressively.

Comment: The data size is far larger than any of the caches, so in effect it's all down to the speed of the SDRAM in your machine. With two or more threads accessing different memory areas all the time the memory controllers simply cannot run the SDRAM efficiently, so it slows down. Memory is not the magical limitless resource that many assume it to be; you have to consider the memory pressure resulting from an algorithm, cache sizes, etc.

Comment: @dascandy Thanks in advance. I use release actually. Can you help  test my code in Linux platform?

Comment: @Dai Thanks. I would try that later on.

Comment: Btw, try to use vector reserve so it won't reallocate space.

Comment: @Satus: AFAICT, there is no vector resizing in the hot parts of the code.

Comment: @yzt yeah, I just saw that

Comment: The code is doing 500M multiplies and adds, plus reading 2x4x500M=4GB of memory. Even the single-threaded version seems too slow, let alone the multi-threaded ones.

Comment: Note that CPU utilization doesn't tell you anything about the **physical** number of cores being used.

Comment: @Mehrdad Thanks!! I open the task moniter to check the 4 Core usage. When I use four threads, the 4 Core is highly used. CPU is  I3-3220. Did you mean that I haven't acutally used the physical core? So how can I enable that?

Comment: Oh, I said that because you said you're only running 2 threads. 4 threads would obviously use all the cores, so if you're seeing 100% on all of them then it's obviously using all the physical cores.

Comment: @yzt Thanks! Can you rougly give the running time for reference?

Comment: Not reproducible here with TDM-GCC 5.1.0. Note that the `clock` function according to the standard should return **consumed CPU time**, but on Windows it returns **wall time**. If you are using C++11, you are better off using `std::chrono`.

Comment: @n.m.: Isn't the standard definition of `clock` ill-defined for a multithreaded program though? The Windows one seems well-defined.

Comment: @yzt Visual C++ uses a checked STL implementation which validates iterators before every access. Last time I checked, this was always enabled, even in release mode. Maybe this could explain the low performance of the single-threaded version. Try disabling it with `#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` and `#define _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING 0`.

Comment: @Jens Not on the latest VS versions. Starting from VS2010 it is disabled for released mode.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. The times on my system are: 0.535, 0.383 and 0.287 seconds for 1, 2 and 4 threads. I'm on an old i7-920, Win7 64-bit and VS2015.

Comment: @yzt same here, everything works just fine here as well, both in debug and release mode (debug being slower ofc)

Comment: Any anti-virus program is scanning it while executing this program ?

Comment: @Jens: That hasn't been true in release mode since VS2010. Also, `_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` has no bearing on this. *And*, the OP is using GCC.

Comment: @yzt Ok, my VC++ skills are little bit rusty. But thanks for the info.

Comment: @user3409554: Your code seems fine. The operations you are doing are too light (only a multiply and add) but you are doing everything correctly. There are no false sharing, no cache thrashing, no locking, no pointer aliasing that might result in false sharing or thrashing, no nothing! Your compiler or runtime library might be doing something fishy though, because I'm seeing numbers that are at least 30x better than yours on VC. Can you check using another compiler?

Comment: @Mehrdad Windows function may be well-defined, but its definition flatly contradicts the standard. POSIX has no problem with it, it reports total CPU time of all used CPUs (thus the result may be 40 seconds for a program that runs for 10 seconds according to the wall clock and occupies 4 CPUs)

Comment: @n.m.: Does it really? The notion of time is already ill-defined in C. There is no guarantee that calling `clock()` in the beginning of the program should result in any particular value (such as zero), and furthermore there is no guarantee that spawning a second thread should make `clock` increase twice as fast. If you're looking at it strictly, it's not a contradiction, because it's not violating any guarantees. If you're looking at it loosely, I would argue the Windows definition is more useful anyway.

Comment: @user3409554: Forget the `clock()` function! Look at your watch... Does your program take 22 seconds to run with 4 threads? If in doubt, use this code to read current time: `chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` and this code to calculate the difference between two time points: `chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(t1 - t0).count()`. They need the standard header `<chrono>`.

Comment: @Mehrdad The term "CPU time" is unambigous and well-understood. All POSIX systems in existence do what I have said. When you rent CPU time on a time-shared system, you get billed according to this notion of CPU time.

Comment: @n.m. You're missing the point. The standard only describes the behavior on an abstract machine, not a physical machine. With regards to that, time is ill-defined in C. Specifically, a machine that decides to slow down or speed up unpredictably for each thread can still be in perfect compliance with the standard. So as far as the standard is concerned, the behavior your program sees in Windows is in perfect compliance. It's unfortunate that it's unintuitive, but that doesn't make it contradictory.

Comment: It has already been touched upon, but I suggest finding out the cache line length of your CPU, then pre-read two chunks of the vectors into two cache lines and do the dot product on those chunks. Then read in two new chunks, and so on

Comment: @Mehrdad The C standard says: "The clock function determines the processor time used." and "The clock function returns the implementation’s best approximation to the processor
time used by the program since the beginning of an implementation-defined era related only to the program invocation". Windows has a perfectly good approximation of the processor time, obtained via `GetProcessTimes`, that is consistent with the POSIX interpretation. One can see this value in the "CPU time" column in the task manager. Why the current  implementation of `clock` is considered better than that is beyond me.

Comment: @n.m.: This is getting very language-lawyery, but doesn't "the implementation" refer to the C standard library implementation rather than the OS implementation? As a language lawyer (which is the case here, since we're talking about compliance) we can argue that its best approximation is indeed what it is returning, irrespective of whether the OS has a more accurate function available. As for usefulness, I consider `clock` more useful because, well, I've had more use cases for it (such as benchmarking, e.g. for this very question!) whereas I've rarely needed the other definition.

Comment: @n.m.: Again, to put it another way: no valid C program can use standard library features to correctly distinguish between a "correct" and an "incorrect" implementation, so as far as the abstract machine is concerned, both behaviors are correct, because the correctness of the specification of the abstract machine only depends on observable (I/O) behavior, not timing.

Comment: @Mehrdad you have all the information and can decide for yourself. I'm not going to convince you.

Comment: @yzt Thanks so much! I will check my complier. I think GCC in DevC++ is different from VC, right?

Comment: Thanks so much for anyone discussing this topic!!

Comment: @yzt [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348228/code-runs-6-times-slower-with-2-threads-than-with-1) I try the method in this link, adding the -O2 optimation in GCC complier. The time now is comparable to yours.

Comment: @user3409554: In one of the first comments, you said that you are using "release", when someone asked whether you are in "debug" or "release" mode. You made a mistake there. If you are not optimizing the code (and/or linking with debug version of the standard library) then you are in "debug" mode, and not in "release" mode. However, that lingo technically applies only to Visual Studio, but I guess it is expected that users of other compilers at least know what people are referring to when saying "building in debug or release mode".

Comment: @user3409554: Just know that all of this basically useless discussion wouldn't have happened if you hadn't said this: "I use release actually."

Comment: you should probably delete this question

Comment: @yzt Sorry for my confusion. Because the complier in DEV-C++ I choose is GCC 4.9.2 64 bit Release. I am not sure that is still in debug mode. Further, I said I am using GCC not VS