# Sorting seems to be slower with 2 threads instead of 1

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, sorting, mergesort

I'm beginning with threads in *Python*, and trying to implement a merge sort where, at the beginning, the job gets splitted into 2 threads. I'm using `collections.deque`, `itertools.islice`, `threading.Thread`.

I create two threads at the beginning, they do each half the job normally, then I join them and merge the result. But I noticed that **it takes way longer (almost 2 twice as long) with two threads than it does when I do it normally**.

How can this be possible ? [Here is a link to the code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/134542/110796), I can reproduce the main parts here if needed (I posted that question on [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) too, and I'd rather keep this one short)

Is it linked to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17348228/5018771) question (seems to be a similar problem in *C++*) ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python multi-threading slower than serial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789042/python-multi-threading-slower-than-serial)

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: Although CPython's GIL limits multithreading, you can still use `multiprocessing`.

Comment: @EliKorvigo - assuming at least some shared memory is needed, won't that still be a problem even when multi-processing?

Comment: @rcgldr `multiprocessing` has some low-level shared memory primitives that are a pain to use, but GIL is not a problem there.

Comment: The C++ problem was due to both threads updating adjacent variables at a high frequency. I've written a bottom up merge sort (C / C++) that splits up an array into 4 parts, using a thread on each part (so 4 threads) to do the merge sort, then 2 threads to merge the quarter parts into half parts, and then one thread to merge the two halves. Depending on array size, it runs about 3 times as fast as a single threaded merge sort.

Comment: @EliKorvigo - By problem with multi-processor shared memory, I meant performance problem related to updates of the shared memory, not an implementation problem.

Comment: @rcgldr yes, there will be a lot of overhead, hence it's only rational to use multiprocessing (especially when there is shared memory involved) when the input task is relatively big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can this be possible?

Unlike C++, Python is quite difficult to parallelize because of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

While `collections.deque`'s `append` and `popleft` are thread-safe, this does not guarantee that they'll perform well in a non-serial paradigm.

> Is it linked to this question?

No. The GIL is a property of CPython. It is totally disjoint from false sharing.

> It takes way longer (almost 2 twice as long) with two threads than it does when I do it normally.

This is because the GIL doesn't support shared memory multithreading. As such, you're essentially running your code serially **twice**.

Comment: So you mean I cannot ever make this faster with only multi-threading ? What could I do ?

Comment: @BusyAnt I don't recommend Python for multi-threaded applications. Prefer C++, Java, Scala, or almost anything else.

Comment: Ok I'll remember that. Could you say what is eating my program's performance here though ? Thread creation ?  Switching between threads ? Something else ? I'm not sure I've fully understood here...

Comment: @BusyAnt The GIL doesn't really allow shared memory, so you're basically running the serial code twice.

Comment: Note that you can make applications faster with **multiprocessing** - this avoids the GIL problem.